# Discrete to Continuous Representations of Functions via Laplace Transforms?

Tags: laplace-transform

The Laplace transform can be thought of as the continuous analogue of a power series, as in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=zvbdoSeGAgI).

From this perspective, think of the function $ a : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as a function giving the coefficients of the taylor series of a function $f$ in $ f(x) = \sum _{i=0}^\infty a(n)x^n$. In other words the 'sequence' $a$ is a discrete representation of the function $f$. What is the continuous analogue? Can we use this to find a continuous representation for the function $f$? We basically want:

$$ f(x) = \sum _{i=0}^\infty a(n)x^n \rightarrow f(x) = \smallint_0^\infty a(t) x^t dt$$

Then applying 'cosmetic' adjustments like $ x = e^{\ln(x)}$, $ x^t = e^{t\ln(x)}$ & $ \ln(x) = - s$ we get

$$ f(x) = \sum _{i=0}^\infty a(n)x^n \rightarrow f(x) = \smallint_0^\infty a(t) e^{-st} dt = F(s)$$

So every time you apply the Laplace transform to a function, you can interpret it as saying that we are saying that this function, restricted to lying over $\mathbb{N}$, represents the Taylor series of some other function, & the continuous representation we've been given is merely a tool we're using in finding a continuous representation of that other function via the Laplace transform.

Is there any general relationship between $a(n)$ & $a(t)$? The fact that Laplace transforms can be taken for functions without Taylor expansions would seem to indicate there isn't, however maybe there is a relationship of Laplace transforms to general sequences?

Comment: You can compute the Laplace transform of each monomial. This is the only connection I can think of right now.

Comment: Ok, maybe I'm a little confused about your $s$, $t$ and $x$. Please clarify.

Comment: I'm just going off of what the guy in that video does, trying to flesh the idea out, so if they are confusing he does motivate them in the video. What is confusing about them?

Comment: Please check variables in your last equation.